# Entity Framework 5.0 query results are different from a direct SQL query on the database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-5

So I've got a very simple query (against a single table) that is returning a different result set when run from Entity Framework vs when it's run directly SQL Server Management Studio. At first I thought EF was generating different SQL, but after rewriting it to be a direct SQL query it's still returning a different result.

Working Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users 
WHERE IsActive = 1 
  AND IsAdvisor = 1 
ORDER BY Initials
```

Failing Code:

```
//var query = this.BaseDB.Users.Where(x => x.IsAdvisor && x.IsActive).OrderBy(x => x.Initials); 
var query = this.BaseDB.Users.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Users.IsActive = 1 AND Users.IsAdvisor = 1 ORDER BY Initials");
return query.ToList(); //this query (either variant, returns the same result set, but is missing values.
```

Any idea what's happening? By the way, I did double check to make sure I was querying the same DB.

Comment: AFAIR EF does not touch the query if you use SqlQuery so it should produce the same result. If it does not make sure you are connecting to the same database.

Comment: Are either of the fields IsActive or IsAdvisor booleans?

Comment: If `IsAdvisor` and `IsActive` is an integer in the database, then `x.IsAdvisor` can't be resolved to a boolean value. If they are integers, just check the int value in the query, `var query = this.BaseDB.Users.Where(x => (x.IsActive == 1) && (x.IsAdvisor == 1)).OrderBy(x => x.Initials).ToList();`

Comment: Run a trace against the database and check what's actually executed.

Comment: What does *different result* mean? Is EF returning a subset of the rows you expect? Different rows entirely? No rows at all? Please clarify and post the schema of the `Users` table.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thanks for the responses. This was my own mistake, the previous developer was setting the display property for certain records individually :(, EF was returning the correct result set.